# Laravel 5 route same urls login or not

Tags: php, authentication, routes, laravel-5, middleware

I am updating a site from  Laravel 4 to 5. In L4 I had this set up:

```
if(Sentry::check()){ 
  Route::get('/', array('as' => 'school.home.index', 'uses' => 'school\AuthSchoolController@index'));
else{
 Route::get('/', 'school\SchoolController@index');
}
```

Note the same url but different controllers depending on login or not.

With L5 I cannot use the middleware tried this:

```
Route::get('/', 'SchoolController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{   
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'school.home.index', 'uses' => 'AuthSchoolController@index'));
});
```

But this just passes over the first and goes to the group, where it gets redirected to the login page and to the admin if logged in.

So I think I need an if/else equivalent in the route based on login but Auth::user() for doesn't seem to work:

```
if(Auth::check()){
  Route::get('/', array('as' => 'school.home.index', 'uses' => 'AuthSchoolController@index'));
}
else{
 Route::get('/', 'SchoolController@index');
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code up for the if/else Auth::user()

Comment: I've added but this doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Are you using Sentry or Eloquent auth in your upgraded version?

Comment: I'm using the built-in auth package

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if( Auth::check() ) {
        return app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\SchoolController')->callAction('index', []);
    } else {
        return app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\AuthSchoolController')->callAction('index', []);
    }    
});
```

Comment: Note: This approach will prevent you from using route caching.

Answer (score -1):

Try reordering the routes like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{   
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'school.home.index', 'uses' =>     'AuthSchoolController@index'));
});

Route::get('/', 'SchoolController@index');
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that defaults to the second route even if someone is logged in. Because the middleware only seems to work for redirecting, if it is the same url, then is does the first and then does the second.

Comment: No answers I see. Really wish I hadn't started with Laravel!

Comment: Need more code examples then. If it's passing the first then it simply means its not being authorized. Have you checked your authnetication code?

Comment: Also, the same url going to different controllers is a bad idea. Think of routes as an array of urls matched up to destinations. The last "key" in the array will always overwrite similar keys above it if the array is to be enforced with unique keys. Which might be an analogy of what's happening here.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to go the long way around and use auth within the controllers.

Comment: That will significantly increase your dev time, in terms of missed logic and edge cases, way higher than the increment needed to reorganize your auth middleware logic. This is laravel 5 auth. It's been successfully setup and done hundreds of thousands of times. I'm sure your situation only requires a bit more insight into the problem....but to each his own